# Getting Error : unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe2b1e71b90 while retrieving data from NSUserDefaults object

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, nsdata

Getting Error : unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe2b1e71b90 while retrieving data from NSUserDefaults object

Mycode is :

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *archiveArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[_StarredImageUrl addObject:[_photoURLsLargeImage  objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag]];

NSData *personEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_StarredImageUrl];
[archiveArray addObject:personEncodedObject];
[defaults setObject:archiveArray forKey:@"items"];
[defaults synchronize];
NSLog(@"Starred URL : %@",_StarredImageUrl);

NSLog(@"Starred URL : %@",personEncodedObject);
NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *encodedObject = [defaults1 objectForKey:@"items"];
NSLog(@"%@",encodedObject);
_SavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
```

I am trying to save the photoUrl's array in NSUserDefaults and loading data from the same NSUserDefaults for the purpose of verifying whether I have saved the data correctly.

But I am getting error in the last line of code, have searched online on various portals, could not resolve , can someone please help.

Full Error :

```
2016-04-10 01:07:39.797 FlickrP[4450:156655] -[__NSCFArray bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe2b1e71b90
2016-04-10 01:07:39.848 FlickrP[4450:156655] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe2b1e71b90'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fcb6e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f3a6deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fcbf48d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc0c90a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc0c4b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc21dc0 CFStringCreateFromExternalRepresentation + 32
    6   Foundation                          0x000000010ef953c6 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithData:encoding:] + 115
    7   FlickrP                             0x000000010ee9eb7b -[ResultstTable Imagetapped:] + 731
    8   UIKit                               0x000000011054be73 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 153
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001105484e5 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 162
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001105464e2 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 843
    11  UIKit                               0x000000011054e9a0 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke904 + 79
    12  UIKit                               0x000000011054e83e _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 342
    13  UIKit                               0x000000011053c101 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 2634
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001100d3f8a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1137
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001100d51c0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 849
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000110083b66 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    17  UIKit                               0x000000011005dd97 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fbe2a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fbd895c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fbd7e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fbd7828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113491ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000110063610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    24  FlickrP                             0x000000010ee9cebf main + 111
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001123f292d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: You left out the important part of the error. Show the full error in your question and point out which line exactly is causing the error.

Comment: HI,I have added the full error, am getting this error in the last line of code:     _SavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];

Comment: You are passing an `NSArray` instead of `NSData` to the `unarchiveObjectWithData:` method.